# viewControllerBeforeViewController is not called every time in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have implemented `UIPageViewController` in my application.

I have implemented two `delegate` methods which returns view for particular Index.

And Also i am detecting forward and backward direction from these methods.

```
  - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

  - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Now the problem is that sometimes `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` are not called but Pagination works fine. Due to this i am not able to find Direction.

Also I have implemented Custom Page Control and I am finding current Index from these methods. When These method not called my PageControl is now working find.

I am not able to find any solution for this.

Comment: are you able to find a solution? Facing same issue.

Comment: @iAmd yes... i fixed that. what problem you  are facing?

Comment: saw your answer below but not sure if it still solves the issue of viewControllerAfterViewController being called sometimes and sometimes not. does it?

Comment: @iAmd well this method doesn't have any relation. What you want to acheive please let me know only then I can say something.

Comment: @iAmd for me viewControllerAfterViewController method was problem because I need to find the Index. And i was not called every time. So using below method solved. What do you want to acheive?

Comment: the didFinishAnimating method will work in my case which you have provided in your answer. There is nothing unusual which i want to achieve. I am only curious why viewControllerAfterViewController is not being called all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Some how I manage to find the Index in this delegate method.

Whenever I am returning `ViewController` for `PageController` I am setting its `Index` value in respective view controller and Finding this `Index` as:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

    UIViewController * viewController = [pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

    CustomViewController *childCtrlr = (CustomViewController*)viewController;

    NSUInteger currentPageIndex = [(CustomViewController *)viewController index];

}
```